# How to change the colour of the correct answer on a javascript quiz

Tags: javascript, colors

I am making a javascript quiz: multiple choice with four options. When the answer is correct, I want it turn green before moving onto the next question, if incorrect I want it to turn red and the correct answer to flash green

Edits I have tried make the colour carry over into the next question. Any suggestions?

```
var currentQuestion =0;
var score = 0;
var totQuestions = questions.length;

var container = document.getElementById('quizContainer');
var questionEl = document.getElementById('question');
var opt1 = document.getElementById('opt1');
var opt2 = document.getElementById('opt2');
var opt3 = document.getElementById('opt3');
var opt4 = document.getElementById('opt4');
var nextButton = document.getElementById('nextButton');
var resultCont = document.getElementById('result');

function loadQuestion(questionIndex) {
var q = questions[questionIndex];
questionEl.textContent = (questionIndex +1)+ '.' + q.question;
opt1.textContent = q.option1;
opt2.textContent = q.option2;
opt3.textContent = q.option3;
opt4.textContent = q.option4;};


document.getElementById('opt1').onclick = function   loadNextQuestion    (){
var selectedOption = document.getElementById('opt1');

var answer = 1;
if(questions[currentQuestion].answer == answer){
score +=1;
}
selectedOption.clicked = false;
currentQuestion++;
if(currentQuestion == totQuestions - 1) {
nextButton.textContent = 'Finish';
 }
if (currentQuestion == totQuestions) {
container.style.display ='none';
resultCont.style.display = '';
resultCont.textContent = 'You scored ' + score;
return;
}
loadQuestion(currentQuestion);
}
```

Repeated three times four opt2, opt3 and opt 4

Comment: Have you tried `someButtonElement.style.backgroundColor = "green"` ?

Comment: Yes I thought that could work... but I don't know how to make it reset: it carries the green over into the next question

Comment: When you need to reset it, just do `someButtonElement.style.backgroundColor = null;`

Answer (score 0):

This is solved via CSS.  You can apply classes to your selected elements as the state requires.  I'm not sure which element in your code represents a "correct" answer, but you would get a reference to that and add or remove a class as necessary.  Ex:

```
document.querySelector('.myCorrectAnswerElement').classList.add('greenSuccessClass');
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this sample will help you .

HTML:

```
<div id="item" > I am just a div</div>
    <button id="yes">yes</button>
    <button id="no">no</button>
```

CSS :

```
    #item{
    width: 500px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

JS :

```
var item = document.getElementById("item");
var yes = document.getElementById("yes");
var no = document.getElementById("no");

yes.onclick = function(){
    item.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}

no.onclick = function(){
    item.style.backgroundColor = "green";
}
```